# Can I travel to Serbia with my Romanian residence permit that is nearly expired to renew my visa?

Tags: visas, study, romania, student-visas, serbia

I am a student in Romania and I need a visa for get new Residence permit of Romania.
And also can I get visa for Romania from Serbia with my Residence Permit?

Comment: What's your nationality? What travel document you want to use to travel to Serbia? Do you really want to see Serbia, or do you just need to get out of Romania to apply for a Romanian visa?